# Laravel events no response body returnd to Stripe

Tags: laravel, events, stripe-payments, webhooks

After successful purchase is made on my website, stripe fires a webhook to finalize the transaction.

What is happening is I am firing 2 laravel events:

1. Send email confirmation of order to the customer
2. Send email notification to admin of site alerting them to the purchase.

If I just fire the event to send email confirmation to customer, the stripe webhook is successful.

When I add the notification to admin, Stripe advises that the HTTP Status Code has timed out that there was no response body and the web hook fails, even though all the emails were sent correctly. And what will happen is stripe will attempt to refire the webhook which is not what I want.

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: What queue driver are you using to process your events? It sounds like you're using a synchronous queue driver which means Stripe has to wait for you to send the mails. If you use an asynchronous queue driver, you can push the email events onto your queue, return a response to Stripe and your queue driver can handle the events later.

Comment: Hi Delena thanks for your comment. I am using a synchronous queue driver at the moment. I am looking to implement an asynchronous queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DelenaMalan is correct, once you receive a Stripe webhook event you should immediately acknowledge receipt by returning a 200 response and then handle your business logic like sending emails afterwards. See https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/build#return-a-2xx-status-code-quickly

Comment: Do you happen to know how long Stripe waits for a response? The docs don't seem to specify.

Comment: There's no explicit timelimit that I'm aware of, but really it shouldn't matter as you should acknowledge receipt as soon as you get the event.

Comment: Additionally, it's worth adding Stripe will keep trying to send events until you give them the response they want. This *can* result in duplicates if you don't handle it properly.